# Create unsigned byte for serial port use

Tags: java, serial-port, byte, unsigned

I need to write a java program that will send byte through serial port. I am using the rxtx library. The problem is that in Java everything is signed, and in one byte I need to send `0xfc`, but in Java this is signed, and it defined as -4. So how can I make an unsigned byte in java, so that in one byte I can send from 0 to 255?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work

```
public static int unsignedToBytes(byte b) {
    return b & 0xFF;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's fine - you can just cast where required. If you have an API which lets you send bytes, and you send a byte of -4 in Java, the *bit pattern* will be the same as for an unsigned byte 0xfc.

If you have a value as an `int` or `short` in the range 0-255, just cast that to `byte`, and again it will represent the right bit pattern, even though the value will become negative if the original value was above 127.

Answer (score 0):

For a byte `b` , `b & 0xFF` will return the unsigned integer value .. will that be okay for you??